# ArcPy Check if layer is finished drawing

Tags: arcpy, raster

I have a script that creates a kind of time series by toggling on and off a bunch of raster layers in sequence. I have a counter that waits a certain amount of time before going to the next raster.

However, sometimes the raster layer does not finish drawing before going onto the next raster layer. The only way currently I have to get around this is by increasing the wait time in the counter.

I am after a way to check if a layer is finished drawing before the counter starts.

I tried the following function to no avail.

```
def wait_for_layer_to_render(layer, max_wait_time=15):
start_time = time.time()
while not arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer).isSupported and time.time() - start_time < max_wait_time:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done in python, the event you're looking for is DrawCompleteEvent https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/sdk/api-reference/topic12634.html ; Desktop had the ability to use comtypes, not sure if that works in Pro but AFAIK you couldn't create an event listener.